# Changes are not show after run production mode in laravel vue + vite

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, vue.js, vite

I run my project after running the command "npm run build" It generates files, also when I run this project it changes my URL like localhost:8000/build/dashboards, I delete a hot file in a public directory, and now the project is run but the changes do not show in production mode why?

I want to resolve this issue

i want to run project in production and changes are shown

Comment: what you want is very much against the nature of production mode.  if you need hot reloading, use dev mode.  explain your case since this is XY problem anyhow, and "I want to" isn't very strong reasoning.